# raspbian-output-video-camera-to-3-5-lcd

Tags: raspbian, camera, video, touchscreen, output

I have a pi3, pi camera and kookye 3.5"lCD. On power up the OS is displayed on the 3.5 screen and the touchscreen works fine. When I run the camera it doesn't out put to the 3.5lcd. Likewise when I play video it doesn't output to 3.5lcd. When I attach HDMI the OS is still displayed on the 3.5lcd however the video and camera output are shown on the HDMI.

How do I change the camera and video output to display on 3.5lcd.

I'm new to raspberry so explanation will have to be simple. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If the screen is operating from the GPIO pins (I must admit I'm not familiar with the Kookye 3.5" LCD) then the short answer is: you don't. From the [picamera FAQ](http://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.12/faq.html#the-preview-doesn-t-work-on-my-pitft-screen):

> #### 5.4. The preview doesn’t work on my PiTFT screen
>
> The camera’s preview system directly overlays the Pi’s output on the HDMI or composite video ports. At this time, it will not operate with GPIO-driven displays like the PiTFT. Some projects, like the Adafruit Touchscreen Camera project, have approximated a preview by rapidly capturing unencoded images and displaying them on the PiTFT instead.

As mentioned in the answer, you can *approximate* the camera's preview but be aware that it generally lacks the "smooth" framerate that the "real" preview system manages (simply because there's a lot more work involved).

Answer (score 1):

You need a program which copies the hardware-accelerated preview from the HDMI/Composite output
to a Linux Framebuffer.

https://github.com/AndrewFromMelbourne/raspi2fb/

would be a good choice.