# Camera OV5647 + 3.5 LCD as a real time view

Tags: pi-3, camera, real-time

I have a OV5647 camera and 3.5 GPIO LCD. I would like to connect both of them to have a real time view in my Raspberry Pi 3. I would like to also set by programming to turn on the camera after some action: During some signal from outside(another pin has a signal) this camera will start work. When a signal from outside will stop, the camera will stop work too.

To do this, I need to have a LCD which can display view from camera in real time. So, I bought those camera and lcd.

But as I read on this topic:

[raspbian-output-video-camera-to-3-5-lcd](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/55088/raspbian-output-video-camera-to-3-5-lcd/55238#55238)

I can't use this LCD for my project, yes?

In this case, does somebody have another solution, which can help me to resolve this challenge?

I would be thankful for any help from you.

Regards

Comment: By real time do you mean that the lag between cam and lcd must be under 1 milisecond?

Comment: The Pi scren can be a bit pricey but gets around a couple of issues 1) it doesn't use/block all the GPIO pins - instead it has a ribbon cable (and only uses a few of the GPIO pins for touch support. It is faster than most GPIO screens.

Comment: @vaha It would be great, but I'm not sure if this 1 mS lag is possible.. This camera will be used in the car for a front view.

Comment: @SteveRobillard I use ArduCam OV5647 5 mpx and it's dedicated for Raspberry with FFC/FPC connection.

Comment: Sorry I meant the Pi LCD screen not cam

Comment: @SteveRobillard Can you send me some example of the LCD which you're talking about? i.e what about a HDMI TFT touchscreen? Will it work with real time view? True be told, I see 7'' lcd with hdmi it's quite too large size. Good size is around 3.5"-5" for my project. Thanks.

Comment: https://www.adafruit.com/products/2718

Comment: @SteveRobillard Thanks for a link. Si, in this case I can run a real time view with this camera and your LCD which you send? In this case, this LCD 7" it's not a Pi TFT,  is it? As in another topic, there was an explanation that with GPIO PiTFT will not work.

Comment: That is the official Pi TFT screen and why wont it work? depending on your definition of realtime you are going to have trouble with the Pi as Linux is not a real time OS.

Comment: @SteveRobillard Now, I understand. The problem is with GPIO during real time view. Could you tell me, how a big latency I can have with this PiTFT 7", which you send? I would like to use this for the car (front side) and it could be good if latency is less than 1 second.

Comment: Without knowing what the rest of your application is doing I can't give you a specific number. I would suggest trying it out.

Comment: @SteveRobillard Ok. Thank you for your suggestion. I will buy this LCD which you send (maybe with less screen size) and I will let you know how it's going. Regards

Comment: If you already have a monitor or small LCD why don't you start  with that. Also are you planning to use this to simply record the forward view from the car or drive the car by using this image?

Comment: @SteveRobillard You're right. I will connect this for tv, at first. I would like to use it for drive a car by using this image (real time view).

Comment: I would hate to be your insurance company. So how did the accident happen well I ran over the 80 yr old lady because of the latency of my 3g uploaded image. I was at home watching the game and decided to use my robocar to the store to pick up some more beer.

Comment: @gryzek Follow these steps: 1. Make the cam working (test with raspistill).  2. Make the LCD working (enough to see the black console screen). 3. Stream from the cam to the LCD. After you succeed in the first 2 steps, then we all will  be in the same line.